# Download files to different paths

Tags: vba, web-scraping

Please help. I have a code that deals

1. Navigate to internet explorer using URL provided in the sheet. - A column
2. Assign the name to the file using names provided in the sheet. - B column
3. This will save downloaded file to specific folder path mentioned in excel sheet. - C column

I have a macro which can do everything, but I am struggling to work on 3rd step. Could you please help me in this?

**MY Question**: I want to download the files to **specific** folder, which keeps on changing.
Example: Some ABC files should download to XYZ folder
         Some CDE files should download to 123 folder
Multiple Folders with different names are already created... Means i need to dynamically change the folder path as per my need.

Here's VBA macro I have for your reference:

```
#If VBA7 And Win64 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal 
pCaller As LongPtr, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As LongPtr, 
ByVal lpfnCB As LongPtr) As Long
#Else
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As 
Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As 
Long) As Long
#End If
Dim Ret As LongPtr

Sub DownloadFile()
pth = "C:\VBA\"
For Each link In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
fname = Split(link.Address, "/")(UBound(Split(link.Address, "/")))
    Filename = pth & fname
    URLDownloadToFile 0, link.Address, Filename, 0, 0
Next link
End 
End Sub
```

Thanks...

Comment: Is there anything that you will be able to pre-define in terms of which file names will go where? For example, will file "ABC" always download to the folder "123"?

Comment: Samuel Everson, first of all thanks for your immediate reply, NO, based on the Order number i have to move the files to specific folder. For example if column D i having unique number/Name then that ABC file should be moved to that particular D column named folder. This column D folder name will change continuously. I have copied the image for your reference in the question. Thanks

Comment: EX: All the files of ABC and GHI url should be moved to folder 123. simply saying based on column D i have to create folder and move the files to that folder.

Comment: So for your 'ABC' example you want the path to be `C:\Mydocuments\123\Image1`?

Comment: Yes, Samuel Eversion what you analyzed is perfect...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your question code modified to achieve your desired output.

This is assuming you are entering the values onto the worksheet.

```
Sub DownloadFile()

Dim Pth as String
Dim Link As Variant
Dim fname As String

For Each Link In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
fname = Split(Link.Address, "/")(UBound(Split(Link.Address, "/")))
    Pth = "C:\VBA\" & Link.Parent.Offset(0, 3).Value & "\"    'Finds the value of the cell 3 columns to the right of the hyperlink

    'The next 3 lines will create the path you specified in your "pth" variable _
    ' or ignore the error if it already exists - this will ensure you don't get errors _
    ' when saving the file to your folder (incase it hasn't been created for example).
    On Error Resume Next
        MkDir (Pth)
    On Error GoTo 0

    Filename = Pth & fname
    URLDownloadToFile 0, Link.Address, Filename, 0, 0
Next Link
End
End Sub
```

To clarify the changes for future readers;

Assigning the `Pth` as `Pth = "C:\VBA\" & Link.Parent.Offset(0, 3).Value & "\"` in the `For...Next` loop allows us to dynamically choose the folder based on the `Column D` value. `Link.Parent.Offset(0, 3).Value` finds the value of the Cell 3 columns to the right the cell the hyperlink is in - in this case, the hyperlinks are in `Column A` and the folder name in `Column D`.

Comment: Sir, What you did is working fine, but it is creating folder inside the folder. like if it creates folder 123, for the next url it is creating 789 folder inside of 123. which should be in the same path("C:\Mydocuments\" but with different folder name as 789. Can you kindly adjust that.

Comment: Sir, you are really Awesome.. that worked fine.. Hats off sir.. I made a bit change in the code for the line Filename = pth & fname to (= pth & Link.Range.Offset(,1)&"."&ext) then it worked for pulling the files from the source.. Really thanks a lot for you hard work and time.... I marked this as Accepted. Thanks a lot again.